# Connection to rabbitmq system process failing from docker container

Tags: docker, go, rabbitmq, native, docker-container

- I have rabbitmq running as a native system process on my local machine
- I have a microservice written in golang that I have packaged into a docker image and I am trying to run that image in a docker container
- This microservices connets to rabbitmq in the following way:

```
    rmq_string := fmt.Sprintf("amqp://%s:%s@%s:%d/", conf.RabbitMQ.Username, conf.RabbitMQ.Password, conf.RabbitMQ.IP, conf.RabbitMQ.Port)
```

with this being the configuration:

```
[RabbitMQ]
PORT = 5672
Username = "guest"
Password = "guest"
IP = "192.168.0.101"
```

when I try to create and run the container using

```
docker run \
  -p 8000:8081 \
  -v "$(pwd)/config.toml":/app/conf/config.toml \
  --name authentication \
  authentication
```

I get the following error:

time=2023-12-10T19:52:21.278Z level=INFO msg="RMQ connection string: amqp://guest:guest@192.168.0.101:5672/"
time=2023-12-10T19:52:21.279Z level=ERROR msg="could not connect to rabbitMQ: dial tcp 192.168.0.101:5672: connect: connection refused\n"

note that when I run the microservice as native process and replace the IP in the conf to localhost it works fine.192.168.0.101 is the IP address of interface en0 I got when I run ipconfig getifaddr en0. interface en1 does not have IP address but I guess it's not used here either ways. also I am connecting psql the same way and it works fine.

for reference my OS is ventura 13.3

I tried to check if rabbitMQ is the one blocking the connection, however I could not fnd it's configuration file, so I created etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config in /usr/local/ and put in it

```
[
  {rabbit, [
    {tcp_listeners, [5672]}
  ]}
].
```

and I restarted the service, sama issue happened

I also checking rabbitmq logs at /opt/homebrew/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost.log and then I tried creating the container I did not see any new logs printed out. these are the logs I foudn when I tailed, looks like they are logs on the restart I did above

```
2023-12-10 21:48:59.498721+02:00 [info] <0.683.0> started TCP listener on 127.0.0.1:5672
2023-12-10 21:48:59.540217+02:00 [info] <0.497.0> Server startup complete; 7 plugins started.
2023-12-10 21:48:59.540217+02:00 [info] <0.497.0>  * rabbitmq_mqtt
2023-12-10 21:48:59.540217+02:00 [info] <0.497.0>  * rabbitmq_stream
2023-12-10 21:48:59.540217+02:00 [info] <0.497.0>  * rabbitmq_stomp
2023-12-10 21:48:59.540217+02:00 [info] <0.497.0>  * rabbitmq_amqp1_0
2023-12-10 21:48:59.540217+02:00 [info] <0.497.0>  * rabbitmq_management
2023-12-10 21:48:59.540217+02:00 [info] <0.497.0>  * rabbitmq_management_agent
2023-12-10 21:48:59.540217+02:00 [info] <0.497.0>  * rabbitmq_web_dispatch
2023-12-10 21:48:59.686188+02:00 [info] <0.9.0> Time to start RabbitMQ: 2480127 us
```

Any idea what the issue is?

Comment: In general, you cannot access a port on the host from within a docker container. Try running both in docker.

Comment: I do it for postgres, it’s running on port 5432, I just pass the container the PC’s en0 IP and it connects to it. Figured the same thing should work for rabbitmq, I think it could be rabbitMQs configuration, I should set it to accept all IPs this way it accepts the container’s IP, I tried to do this and I put what I did in the response above but I think I am missing something

Comment: This seems very similar to [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach); does one of the answers there help?  As with other things around Docker, if the host RabbitMQ broker is only listening on 127.0.0.1, it may not be able to accept connections coming from a container.

Comment: I just ended up running rabbitmq in a docker container, I will not be using system processes unless 100% needed